# Handling _bstr_t from byte array and back with C#

Tags: c#, encoding, bstr-t

I try to decrypt a given file, but the content stored is done in C++ using the _bstr_t class. I've been searching for 2 hours already, testing everything and I still didn't get the correct result: reading Korean `_bstr_t`'d characters as String.

This is the value read in bytes:

> B5 B8 BF F2 C3 BC

Which should be, as far as I know, something like 'Arial'.
I've tried using the `Encoding.Unicode.GetString()` , `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`, `Encoding.UTF7.GetString()` , `Encoding.UTF32.GetString()` methods, none of them returning correct Korean sentences.

Does anyone have an idea how to convert a _bstr_t'd string, converted to bytes, is readable in C#?

Comment: Do you have access to the C++ code that writes the file out?  Can you post some of it?

Comment: I don't have access to the C++ code, unfortunately :(.

Comment: This is not Korean text, you're probably looking at binary data.  Contact the owner of the code that wrote the file for support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does decoding the bytes with the [Windows codepage for Korean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305154) produce the output you want?

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 0xB5, 0xB8, 0xBF, 0xF2, 0xC3, 0xBC };
var output = Encoding.GetEncoding(949).GetString(bytes);
```